# BIDS - SSIS - Redirect row on Error sends too many rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a simple data flow.
The source is a small flat file with approxiamtely 16k rows in it.
The destination is an OLE DB destination, a SQL 2008 table with a 3 part Unique key on it.
The data flow goes via some simple transformations; Row Count, derived columns, data conversion etc.

All simple and all that works fine.

My problem is that within this data there are 2 rows which are duplicates in terms of the  primary key, 2 duplicate rows that violate that key, so 4 rows in total. On the OLE DB destination i have set the error output to redirect Row and the rows are sent to an Error table which has enough columns for me to identify the bad rows.

The problem is that even though there are 4 cuplrits the tranformation keeps writing 1268 rows to the error table.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**

Just to add, if i remove the 2 duplicate rows the whole file imports successfully....16,875 rows.
There is no question that only 2 rows violate the key, but the error redirection affects 1268.

**

Comment: Have you checked out those 1268 rows, i.e., do they look correct or maybe something else is causing them to error as bobs suggested.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found the solution.

The problem goes away if you load the data using Data access mode 'Table or view' in the OLE Destination rather than 'Table or View - Fast load'.

The only relevant comment i can find is on MSDN;

*Any constraint failure at the destination causes the entire batch of rows defined by FastLoadMaxInsertCommitSize to fail.*

So it seems that the row size was 1268 in my case and the 2 duplicate rows that were violating the key caused the whole batch to be redirected to the error destination table.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the other rows are errors due to the PK violation?  There are a couple of additional columns (ErrorCode, ErrorColumn) available through the error path.  This may show that you have different issues.

Comment: Thanks for that, i did not know you could add those columns. I added them and got the values; error code - -1071607685, which translates in dtsmsg.h to // MessageId: DTS_E_OLEDBDESTINATIONADAPTERSTATIC_UNAVAILABLE
//
// MessageText:
//
// No status is available.
//
#define DTS_E_OLEDBDESTINATIONADAPTERSTATIC_UNAVAILABLE ((HRESULT)0xC020907BL)    and  the error column is 0 - a quick google suggests that this mean an error with the row rather than a column...........so nothing new to go on there.

Comment: This article says that -1071607685 could be FK constraint related: http://dwexperience.blogspot.com.au/2007/10/error-codes-1071607685.html

Comment: Further to "-1071607685" - it was a Unique Index failure for us. (Another empty row). We got more information when we turned off "Redirect Row" error handling and just got the package/step to fail.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL 2008 you can redirect failing rows to e.g. a flat file destination. Go to the destination OLEDB task goto the error output (select all fields in the windows). With the combobox below choose redirect row and apply, then ok.
Next drag a precedance contraint (red arrow) from the OLEDB to a new Flat file task and configure this task (don't change the default mapping of the columns).

Now you should be able to find the error row more easy.

Eric